# findAll doesn't work, nested tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm parsing through [this](https://www.wired.com/2016/08/live-debate-whats-right-kind-intersection) page. I need to get text content - which is located in `p` tags. The general structure of the page is the following:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <article itemprop="articleBody">
            <div...>
               <div...>
                  <figure>
                  <span..></span>
                  <p>THE TEXT</p>
                  </figure>
              </div>
           </div>
        </article>
    </body>
</html>
```

So the `p` is not a direct child of `article` but it is still inside, and `findAll` should be able to find it. But it doesn't.

```
articleBody=soupArticle.find("article", {"itemprop":"articleBody"})
textList=articleBody.findAll("p")
print(len(textList)) #gives 0
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: in the source code of your link, I can see only one `article` tag under which there is no `p` tag. what is your expected output ?

Comment: @akash karothiya, the `p`s are inside div. There are located deeply inside.  I've given just a general structure, the real one is way too complicated. You can find them by looking at text's code.

Comment: All of the texts are inside javascript tags.

Comment: I think you want to extract all tweets and they are located in json format, please see after `CN.omniture.conf =`, here you need to use json package

Comment: @akash karothiya, No, not tweets, just the general text which comes after tweets.

Comment: ok sure, can you please provide sample expected output ( or text )

Comment: `articleBody=soupArticle.find("article", {"itemprop":"articleBody"})`
`textList=articleBody.findAll("p")`
`print(textList[0].text)`
Output: So … I'm not sure who won. But since you're on the Internet, you have an opinion. Please vote here, and we'll see you at our next debate!

Comment: @Daniel Lee, I can see only divs. Is that `<div data-js=" ">` cause the problem?

Comment: `for row in soupArticle.findAll("script",{"type":"text/javascript"}):` will give you all the information that you need. It's in a dictionary or JSON file so you'll have to use another tool to get the text

Comment: You are breaking the ToS by scraping the content so don't be surprised if you get banned, https://www.condenast.com/privacy-policy *Prohibitions on Use of the Service*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import mechanize

url = "https://www.wired.com/2016/08/live-debate-whats-right-kind-intersection"
br = mechanize.Browser()
response = br.open(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')


media = []
 for x in soup.findAll("script",{"type":"text/javascript"}):
media.append(x.get_text().split("*/"))

med = media[4][1].split("<p>")
strin=[]
for i, element in enumerate(med):
    strin.append("")
    for char in element:
        strin[i]+=char
        if char=="<":
            break

for text in strin:
   print text
```

You can encode the texts in 'utf-8' if you want.

Comment: That sort of works, but I can't find the text:
`for i in media: if "who won" in i: print("found")`. Can't find. Maybe there is a way to select specific javascript using `data-js` id's?

Comment: `if "who won" in media[4][1]: print "found"`

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like this:

```
for p in soupArticle.findAll("article", {"itemprop":"articleBody"}):
    textList = p.find_all("p")
    print(len(textList))
```

It probably would help.

Comment: Doesn't help. `Nonetype object` mistake, which means it can't find `p` tags.

Comment: @Daniel Lee, returns only the footer `pGo Back to Top. Skip To: Start of Article.p`

Comment: What is `p.get("p")` supposed to be doing?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, grabbing text of <p> elements from source code of the site

Comment: @OleksandrIvanenko, p tags are not attributes, if you did happen to get a return from get it would definitely not be a list `find_all("p")` or `select("p")` would return a resultSet/list but all the data is populated using react so it won't be in the source under the p tags regardless.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, oh, yeah, you are right, I have a smaple BeautifulSoup code, and I used it all the time. But in this case it didn't help. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The HTML that you see in your browser is not the same as the HTML that you would get if you retrieved it with `urllib`, `requests` or other HTTP client - assuming that that's how you obtain the HTML.

That's because the content that you are after is inserted dynamically into the document with Javascript. You might need to use something like [Selenium webdriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) to programatically control your browser so that the content is rendered via the Javascript.

Take a look at the value of `articleBody` after the `find()`:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.wired.com/2016/08/live-debate-whats-right-kind-intersection'
html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

>>> print soup.article
<article class="content link-underline relative body-copy" data-js="content" itemprop="articleBody">
<a class="visually-hidden skip-to-text-link focusable bg-white" href="#start-of-content">Go Back to Top. Skip To: Start of Article.</a>
</article>
```

This shows that the content is not where you have presumed it to be, it is embedded in the `<script>` tags and dynamically inserted by Javascript when the page is loaded.

Comment: Thank you. Does 'data-js' always indicate that this is the case to be dealt with Selenium?

Comment: @parsecer: No, it doesn't always indicate that. And, because the content is actually contained in the Javascript code that comes with the page, Selenium is not required to execute the Javascript to render the page before you use BeautifulSoup on it. As [Daniel Lee's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39018304/21945) shows, you can extract the content.directly from the `<script>` tags with string manipulation, although it's inelegant and prone to fail if/when the position of the script tag inevitably changes in the document.